# Reverse DNS on Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package

I'm checking a list of requirement to see if we are following the best practices while sending emails on Marketing Cloud and one thing that I should check is about the reverse DNS

If I didn't misunderstand, the email provider will use the IP to check the domain name.

My question is if I need to take any action, we have [SAP](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&type=5) so the IP checked ny the email providers will be the Marketing Cloud and I don't need to do anything? Or because Marketing Cloud sends emails on behalf of our domains I must check if the reverse DNS is implemented on our host?

Also, there is an way to easily validate if the reverse DNS is implemented on our host? An way that I don't need to reach out to IT team, like using an online email validator tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: don't worry. Having an SAP in place ensures proper email authentication.

Like I'm writing in [my article](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/deliverability/ensuring-email-deliverability/), Reverse DNS (PTR) will indeed be taken care of, when sending an email from either an SAP or Private Domain in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

If you want to be 100% sure, you can send an email from your SFMC to https://www.mail-tester.com/ which will let you know, if you have passed all the relevant checks.

Comment: Thank you @Lukas